# move value from one column to another based on condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for moving column A value to column B if it begins with '[' for example if value in column A is = ['Data'] then move it to Column B if not continue searching to match criteria

| Column A | Column B |

|:---- |:------:|

| One  | [Data]|
| [Data] | |

Please advise on how to go about this in Excel

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Day,

If I understand your question correctly this might help. As you see in A1 the value starts with a [, so the formula in B1 adds the value from A1. The value in B2 does not start with a [ so it has no value.

[image]

If not hopefully, this gives you an idea.

Comment: Thanks @BradR, TRIM and LEFT worked and it solves my problem :)
Have a nice day!